How to set an proxy with authentication in Java Selenium WebDriver?
I am working on a web scraping project using Selenium WebDriver with Java. I need to route my web traffic through an external proxy that requires authentication. While I can manually handle the authentication prompt and see the proxy's IP address reflected, I am unable to achieve this programmatically.

What I've Tried:
Setting the proxy with authentication directly:
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress)
     .setSslProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress);

This approach passes the authentication but does not change the browser's IP address to the proxy IP.
Setting the proxy without authentication and manually entering credentials:
proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAddress)
     .setSslProxy(proxyAddress);

When I manually enter the authentication credentials in the browser prompt, the IP address changes as expected.
Code Snippets:
Here’s a example of my code:
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProxyExample {
    public WebDriver test(String Proxyport) {
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        String proxyAddress = "192.1.1.1:" + Proxyport;

        String proxyUsername = "username";
        String proxyPassword = "password";
        String proxyAuth = proxyUsername + ":" + proxyPassword;
        proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);

        // Attempt to set proxy with authentication
        // proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress)
        //      .setSslProxy(proxyAuth + "@" + proxyAddress);

        // Setting proxy without authentication
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyAddress)
             .setSslProxy(proxyAddress);

        options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features");
        options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);

        // Initialize the ChromeDriver with the configured options
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("http://example.com"); // Test the proxy setup

        return driver;
    }
}

How can I properly set an external proxy with authentication in Java Selenium WebDriver? What is the correct approach to handle proxy authentication within the WebDriver, ensuring the browser IP address changes to reflect the proxy IP?
